# conda install downgrade python version

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to downgrade python version of anaconda via `conda install python=3.3`, but have following error:

```
~/anaconda3/bin$ ./conda install python=3.3
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - gevent -> python 2.6*
  - python 3.3*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How to resolve conflicts with the packages?

Comment: Have you tried to run `conda uninstall gevent` first?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you want to set specific version, use it like this:

> **WARNING:** This command will overwrite the default python version **system-wise**

```
conda install python=3.6
```

To create environment with a specific version, you can do:

```
conda create -n $PYTHON36_ENV_NAME python=3.6 anaconda  # set custom env name
```

> The `anaconda` at the end allows the env to use all anaconda packages

For more information refere to [Anaconda documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html)

Comment: Hi. I did `conda install python=3.6.6` but got `3.6.9` installed. How to force conda to install requested version?

Comment: This will not set it as default.

Comment: @CermakM, I think you are right, I want to downgrade python version in Spyder Anaconda from 3.8 to 3.7. I run following commands and a message shows IT MAY TAKE FEW MONUTES, but it is running and running (like half an hour) to solve conflicts:  conda search python                                                                                            conda install python=3.7.0

Comment: well, this command is did not work for me: conda install python=3.7.0,  in Spyder it is still shows Python 3.8.5. I gonna try : conda create --name py33 python=3.3

Answer (score 17):

*There are two ways to downgrade python in anaconda.*

#### 1. Downgrade python in the active environment

(This can *lead to conflicts* with installed packages for higher python versions)

```
conda activate nameOfYourEnvironment
conda install python=3.3
```

---

#### 2. Create a new environment

(This is a more *safer way*, but you need to *reinstall all packages*)

```
conda activate base
conda create --name env_name python=3.3
```

**Hint:** Use `conda list` before creating a new environment to get the names of all installed packages in the recent environment.

---

If you want to check your installed environments, use:

```
conda env list
```

If you had problems with the installation, make sure that you run the shell as administrator (always recommended).

Answer (score 10):

Very firstly check the current version using command `python --version`. Then on anaconda prompt type the command `conda search python` which will list all the python versions available till date. Then from that list select your version and type `conda install python=3.5.2` or any of your choice

Comment: Thank you best way to change the versions

Comment: thanks. This is the nest answer so far for this query....

Answer (score 7):

You can make environments with other versions of Python using this command:

```
conda create --name py33 python=3.3
source activate py33
```

Comment: But, I don't need environment, I need python 3.3 as default python installation.

Comment: Using environments is the supporting way to use a different version of Python. You could also uninstall and reinstall Anaconda with a different Python version.

Comment: This answer requires the least amount of effort.

Comment: The same as the above answer.